# Timestamp in XML Schema

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, timestamp, element

I'm creating an XML schema, where some of the elements should have the timestamp format from sql. There is no type in XML schema that completely correlates, so how can I best achieve this? XML has dateTime, but it's not in the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to let SQL Server create the schema for you. Just try:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTbl(ID INT,SomeDate DATETIME, TheTS TIMESTAMP)

INSERT INTO #tempTbl(ID,SomeDate) VALUES(1,GETDATE()),(2,GETDATE());

SELECT * FROM #tempTbl FOR XML AUTO,XMLSCHEMA

DROP TABLE #tempTbl;
```

The relevant part of the schema should be this:

```
<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="sqltypes:int" />
  <xsd:attribute name="SomeDate" type="sqltypes:datetime" />
  <xsd:attribute name="TheTS" type="sqltypes:timestamp" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

EDIT: You could have a [look here](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/SqlTypes.xsd) The `TimeStamp` is defined as `xsd:base64Binary`